# Checking if username is available in database

Tags: c#, sql, database, dataset

I'm trying to check if the username is already in use in C# database and it's giving me this error

[image]

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\admin\Desktop\241 Project  sem 1 2020-2021\Online Banking - ITIS 241 project group 9\UobBankDatabase.mdf; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30");
cn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from LoginTable where user_name='" + textBox1.Text + "'", cn); 
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read())
{
    dr.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Username Already exist please try another ", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
else
{
    dr.Close(); 
}
```

and yes I'm a newbie

Comment: You're probably in the wrong database. Include an initial catalog in your connection string. Please check table name (LoginTable)

Comment: DO NOT CONCATENATE INPUT - it **must** be `"select * from LoginTable where user_name=@userName"` or similar, and add a parameter named `@userName` with the *value* from `textBox1.Text`. Or use tool like Dapper that makes this much easier. The name "Online_Banking" here alongside SQLi is *terrifying*, honestly.

Comment: [best example](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png) and funny ;)

Comment: @nilsK SQLi and MITM are *very* different things; only SQLi is relevant here

Comment: @MarcGravell ay, thank you. you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) from LoginTable where user_name='" + textBox1.Text + "'", cn);
```

Then:

```
var dr = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (dr != null)
{
    //Exists
}
else
{
    //Unique username
}
```

Comment: No, please dont: please be aware of [SQL injections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-ver15) or 'man in the middle attacks'.

Comment: As explained above, 'man in the middle attacks' is something completly different. My bad. Cant edit now, to late, but will leave the hint here, because the rest is quite important.

Comment: Yes. You are right. He should ideally use AddWithValue. I actually just prefer Entity Framework or Dapper though.

Answer (score 0):

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql%20exception%20invalid%20object%20name&rlz=1C1GCEB_enIR855IR855&oq=sql%20exception%20&aqs=chrome.5.69i57j0l7.10719j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) it please:

> Since the error is SqlException: Invalid object name 'Movie' , that
> means the table named 'Movie' has not created or the Database you are
> referring has not created. To see if the Database or table 'Movie' has
> created, open SQL Server Object Explorer and check the Database name
> is the same as in appsettings. json

And Please tell us at what line do you get that?
Is that this line =>if (dr.Read())

Answer (score 0):

Let's extract method for the check:

```
private static bool NameAvailable(string name) {
  //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
  using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Connection String Here")) {
    cn.Open();

    //DONE: keep Sql readable
    //DONE: make Sql parametrize
    //DONE: select 1 - we don't want entire record but a fact that record exists 
    string sql = 
      @"select 1
          form LoginTable 
         where user_name = @prm_user_name";

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn)) {
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@prm_user_name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;

      using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        return !dr.Read(); // Not available if we can read at least one record
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can put

```
 if (!NameAvailable(textBox1)) {
   // Let's be nice and put keyboard focus on the wrong input
   if (textBox1.CanFocus)
      textBox1.Focus();

   MessageBox.Show("Username Already exist please try another ", 
                   "Error", 
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

some changes only.it is better to get what is the error than a temporary solution so print your query first and run it in the sqlserver . also add initial catalog instead of attacjing mdf files its way better in my opinion.

```
 <connectionStrings>

<add name="stringname" connectionString="Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=databasename; Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

</connectionStrings>
```

using a connection string instead also

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["stringname"].ConnectionString);
        cn.Open();
        string query = "select * from LoginTable where user_name='" +     textBox1.Text.ToString() + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //print query  if error and comment the execute reader section when printing the query to know the error  Respone.Write(query);
            if (!dr.HasRows)
            {
               // ur code to insert InsertItemPosition values
        
            }
            else
            {
                //show username exist
            }
            dr.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnection"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(UserName) as UserCount FROM LoginTable WHERE user_name = @user_name", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_name", TextBox1.Text);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                if(Convert.ToInt32(dr["UserCount"].ToString()) >= 1)
                {
                    // Exists
                }
                else
                {
                    // Doesn't Exist
                }
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```